# Access object in JSON array with this.state in React Native

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, react-native

I am having trouble displaying an object from an array. I want to display `id` from here:

```
    [  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "imagename":"dog"
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "imagename":"cat"
   },
   {  
      "id":"3",
      "imagename":"mouse"
   },
   {  
      "id":"4",
      "imagename":"deer"
   },
   {  
      "id":"5",
      "imagename":"shark"
   },
   {  
      "id":"6",
      "imagename":"ant"
   }
]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
fetch(`http://www.example.com/React/data.php` , {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }

  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
        id: responseJson[0].id, <-- Attempt to try to get the id from responsejson.
        },function() {
          // In this block you can do something with new state.
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

With this I got `undefined is not a function`. I am not getting what I am doing wrong or how to access this object.

```
 <FlatList

       data={ this.state.dataSource}

       ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


       renderItem={({item}) => <View>


       <Card>

         <View>


           <Text style={{marginTop: 30}}> {this.state.responseJson.id}</Text>


         </View>

       </Card>


       </View>


     }

     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

  />
```

Comment: is `responseJson` actually an array?

Comment: Yes, JSON array of objects.

Comment: where have you confirmed data up to in the above sample?

Comment: The snippet at the top displays json encoded data from mysql database correctly and I just copied it to here @Tony

Comment: yeah but have you confirmed any response in the first `then()`, or actually confirmed the array in the second `then()`?

Comment: You are passing an empty callback as a second argument to setState, that's likely what is causing your error here.

Comment: @Jaxx I don't think an empty callback in `setState` causes any issues

Comment: Do you mean a response in the `render()`? Yes, All of the data shows, but I just want `id`. If were to put `responseJson` in a `flatlist`, it all works out. I just added the ` [0].id` as an example.

Comment: Can you share which kindly of response you will get from your api?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I'm sorry, I'm new to react native and I just don't know what you mean by that? Can you give me an example?

Comment: What is the response which you get after calling your api?

Comment: When I use `responseJson` I get a "Success!" message and I can successfully use `{item}` from a flatlist and which ever object I want to use like: 'imagename'. However, It won't let me access this with `this.state` for just a specific object like `id` or `imagename`.

Comment: @LaneyWilliams which line is causing this error `undefined is not a function`, if the code is not over here please update the question.

Comment: @RaajNadar I updated my question above

Answer (score 0):

Try the async/await method, you are getting an error because the data is not load and the render function is trying to load the data.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch(`http://www.example.com/React/data.php`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

    }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: responseJson,
            id: responseJson[0].id
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Or another approach is to add a loading preloader or spinner like this.

First import the package.

```
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
```

Second change the render method

```
render() {
    if (isLoading) {
        return ( <
            View style = {
                [styles.container, styles.horizontal]
            } >
            <
            ActivityIndicator size = "large"
            color = "#0000ff" / >
            <
            /View>
        );
    }
    return (
        // Your render stuffs
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    padding: 10
  }
})
```

If any issue please let me know